# Is there any method in IBM-Cloud-VPC Python SDK that can be used to shut down VSI in IBM Cloud VPC?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I tried this [IBM-Cloud-VPC-Python-SDK](https://pypi.org/project/ibm-vpc/0.11.0/) - But, I don't find any methods in the IBM-Cloud-VPC-Python SDK for shutting down VSI (Virtual Server Instance)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is documented here: https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/vpc/latest?code=python#create-instance-action

```
response = service.create_instance_action(
    instance_id,
    typ='stop',
)
```

Comment: Thank you, it's available in the document.